# how to change jenkins build description "Started by GitLab push by " statement when using gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, pipeline, webhooks

i`m trying to connect jenkins with gitlab by WebHook.
when i push specific branch, webhook call jenkins pipeline.
and each build has a description and that prints "Started by GitLab push by XXX".

now i have a question, can i change that word by myself?
i want to change that to what i want. for example, git commit message or something in Merge Request.

please, let me know!
sincerely.

I tried to search on stackoverflow and google, but I didn`t get the proper way to control it. So I leave a note here .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the build description in Jenkins when triggered by a GitLab webhook.
To do this, you need to add some additional parameters to your Jenkins pipeline script that will allow you to specify the custom build description.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Build started"'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            // Set custom build description based on git commit message
            def customDescription = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B', returnStdout: true).trim()
            
            // Use the custom description if available, otherwise use default message
            currentBuild.description = customDescription ?: "Started by GitLab push by ${env.GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. You solved my problem. so now I can change the pipeline's build description.
if I may ask you one another question? 
I want to call another build job in my pipeline. and can I change the build description of triggered job?

I tried with below code. but It didn't work. please let me know tips for it. and thank you again.

`build job: 'davinci-qa', parameters: [string(name: 'RELEASE_NUM', value: env.gitlabMergeRequestTitle), string(name: 'description', value: env.gitlabMergeRequestTitle)]`